# Update model in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new in rails I have built a form from my model @user

this is my user controller

```
def me
@user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)

if !params.empty?
  @user.update_attributes params[:user]
end
end
```

But I getting this error:

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

this is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :mobile)
  end
end
```

I tried to define here an "update" method, but I get errors like this:

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Any idea?

Comment: Try adding :Id to your permitted Params as a start

Comment: And those permitted params should really be in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a few things here

Your update method should look like this

```
def me
  @user = current_user.find_by(params[:Id])

end
```

You need to have your permitted Params in your controller, and add :Id to those Params

As it looks like your using devise you will need to make your own user controller inheriting from devises controller so that you can override the permitted Params

See the devise docs on how to override the controller as its really simple

Comment: thank you putting the permit into my controller was the solution